# If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable there exist open sets $G_1\supset G_2\supset\dots$ containing $A$ such that $|(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k)\setminus A|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if it is correct and/or/if it could be improved somehow, thanks:

"If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable there exists a decreasing sequence $G_1\supset G_2\supset\dots$ of open sets containing $A$ such that $|\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k\setminus A|=0$"

My proof:

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set: then we know that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set $H\supset A$ such that $|H\setminus A|<\varepsilon$. This implies that for every $n\geq 1$ there exists $H_n\supset A$ open such that $|H_n\setminus A|<\frac{1}{n}$ so if we define for every $k\geq 1$ the set $G_k:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{k} H_k$ we have that the $G_k$s form a decreasing sequence ($G_{k+1}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{k+1}H_k=\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}H_k \cap H_{k+1}\subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{k}H_k=G_k$) of open sets (since each $G_k$ is the intersection of *finitely* many open sets) containing $A$ ($A\subset H_n$ for every $n\geq 1$ implies $A\subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{k}H_n=G_k$).

Now, since for every $m\geq 1$ we have that $(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k)\setminus A\subset G_m\setminus A\subset H_m\setminus A$ and hence $|(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k)\setminus A|\leq |G_m\setminus A|\leq |H_m\setminus A|<\frac{1}{m}$ it follows that $|(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k)\setminus A|=0$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: It seems correct to me in every detail...in the parenthesis you mean $G_k$ is an intersection of open sets

Comment: @MariosGretsas Ah yes of course, it was a typo, now corrected: thanks!